# find number of string matches from array to array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to find number of strings in array `b` that contains in array `arr`. I  got the output but i need it in this order.`[[3,6,0],[1,3,1]]` 
here my code goes.

```
var arr = [["00","00","00","01","01","01","01","01","01"],["000","100","01","01","01"]];
var b = ["00","01",10];
var cc = [];
for (var i=0;i<b.length;i++) {
    var k = [];
    for (var y=0;y<arr.length;y++) {
        var a = 0;
        for (var x=0;x<arr[y].length;x++) {
            if ((arr[y][x].substring(0,2)).indexOf(b[i]) != -1) {
                a++;
            }
        }
        k.push(a)
    }
    cc.push(k);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(cc));// output :[[3,1],[6,3],[0,1]]
```

Actual output : `[[3,1],[6,3],[0,1]]`
Expected output : `[[3,6,0],[1,3,1]]`
I want the result either in javascript or jquery.

Comment: can't understand the logic, what are the `[3,6,0]` and `[1,3,1]` stand for?

Comment: `arr[0]` contains 3 `00` and `01` is 6 and `10` is 0 same to the `arr[1]`

Comment: u have any doubt now @Saar

Comment: `arr[1]` do not contain "00". Still how it's occurrence became 1 in the desired output? same happens for "10".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have in `b` number `10` you need convert it to `String` and then search in array, because `arr` contains only strings

```js
var arr = [
    ["00","00","00","01","01","01","01","01","01"],
    ["000","100","01","01","01"]
];

var b = ["00", "01", 10];

var len, i, j, key, result = [], counts = [], count = 0;

for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {    
    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {     
        count = 0;        
    key = String(b[j]);
        
        count = arr[i].filter(function (el) {
            return el.slice(0, 2) === key;
        }).length;
                
        counts.push(count);
    }
    
    result.push(counts);
    counts = [];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Version for `IE < 9`, where there is not `.filter` method

```js
var arr = [
    ["00","00","00","01","01","01","01","01","01"],
    ["000","100","01","01","01"]
];

var b = ["00", "01", 10];

var len, 
    key,
    result = [],
    counts = [],
    i, j, k, count;

for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {    
    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {     
        count  = 0;        
    key    = String(b[j]);
        
        for (k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
            if (arr[i][k].slice(0, 2) === key) {
             count++;
            }
        }
                
        counts.push(count);
    }
    
    result.push(counts);
    counts = [];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are some typo in your sample input. Following code may help.

```js
var arr = [["00","00","00","01","01","01","01","01","01"],["00","10","01","01","01"]];
var b = ["00","01","10"];
var cc = [];
arr.forEach(function(ar,i){  
  cc[i] = [];
  b.forEach(function(a,j){         
      cc[i][j] = ar.filter(function(d){ return d==a }).length;
  });
});
alert(JSON.stringify(cc));
```

Or

```js
var arr = [
  ["00", "00", "00", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01"],
  ["00", "10", "01", "01", "01"]
];
var b = ["00", "01", "10"];
var cc = arr.map(function(ar) {
  return b.map(function(a) {
    return ar.filter(function(d) {
      return d == a
    }).length;
  })
});
alert(JSON.stringify(cc));
```